# New Blank page after successful login in Angular 4 app

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular4 application and after my first login page I want to go the new blank page. How can I do this in angular 4 app ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

What do you mean by new blank page.

Comment: use route.navigate to go to the new blank page. And create component with no info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a component without any html tags then

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Then pass an object of it inside your component `constructor`

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

Then after a successful login attempt navigate to a new component

```
this.router.navigate(['/WHATEVER']);
```

Of course don't forget to implement a valid route to that new component